# How to use search box control in Windows Phone 8.1 universal apps?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How to use search box control in Windows Phone 8.1 universal apps? When I try to add, I received an error message:

> SearchBox is not supported in a Windows Phone project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN says SearchBox is

> Not recommended for Universal Windows Platform apps.

Try `AutoSuggestBox` instead

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox.aspx

If you still want to try `SearchBox`, try the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413748/how-to-use-searchbox-in-windows-8-1-by-loading-the-results-using-a-async-method) post

Comment: "Query Submitted" is available from Windows 10. Is Windows Phone 8.1, there is another way to detect when a user submits a query?

Comment: `SearchBox` has `QuerySubmitted` in Win8.x. But looks like theres no `QuerySubmitted` for `AutoSuggestBox` in Win8.1.

Try `KeyDown`. Check for Enter / Return key in that event